# Transition from Java interface to C++ code

Tags: c++

I have an Expression interface which holds a method *evaluate*.
I have 3 types of expressions: a number, a cell reference and a binary application between 2 subexpression (for example 5 + 3 is BinaryOp(Number(5), +, Number(3))  ).

Unfortunately, I can't declare a variable of type Expression in order to further evaluate it. How can I solve this?

Expression.h

```
#pragma once

#include "../../spreadsheet/HFiles/Spreadsheet.h"

using namespace std;

class Expression
{
public:
    virtual double evaluate(Spreadsheet &context) = 0;
};
```

BinaryOp.h

```
#pragma once

#include <cmath>
#include <set>
#include <variant>
#include "CellRef.h"

using namespace std;

class BinaryOp : public Expression
{
private:
    Expression leftOperand;
    Expression rightOperand;
    Kind op;

public:
    BinaryOp(Expression left, Expression right,Kind op) {
        this->leftOperand = left;
        this->rightOperand = right;
        this->op = op;
    }

    double evaluate(Spreadsheet &context) override {
        double expr1 = leftOperand->evaluate(context);
        double expr2 = rightOperand->evaluate(context);
        if (op == PLUS)
             return expr1 + expr2;
        else if (op == MINUS)
             return expr1 - expr2;
        return 0.0;
    }
};
```

Number.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Spreadsheet.h"

using namespace std;

class Number : public Expression
{
private:
    double value;

public:
    Number(double value) {
         this->value = value;

    double evaluate(Spreadsheet &context) override {
         return value;
    }
};
```

Comment: In Java, `Expression leftOperand;` is, essentially, what would in C++ be a pointer: `Expression *leftOperand'`.

Comment: Your `BinaryOp` isn't an `Expression`.

Comment: Seems like a great opportunity to learn how to use operator overloading

Comment: @PeteBecker It looks like your suggestion works (at least for now). Thanks!

Comment: @Ruzihm I made a mistake when copying the code. I updated the question.

Comment: @PeteBecker Actually, that would be an `std::shared_ptr<Expression>` in Java, not a raw pointer. Popescu Ion, please read up on smart pointers, handling "owning" raw pointers properly only serves to make your own life much more difficult.

Comment: @AVH I tried something with shared_ptr but it didn't work out.

Comment: @PopescuIon Try some more ;). If you're not using smart pointers (e.g. `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`), I can basically guarantee you that you are leaking memory. In this case, you want to use `unique_ptr`, no need for `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @AVH And how can I use a unique_ptr in the constructor? Because "=" operator doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @PopescuIon I can't properly explain in a comment here. Your best bet is to check Google or StackOverflow for a short introduction. Please do so, it will save you a lot of headaches in the future :).

Comment: @AVH — it might or might not be, depending on how the C++ application manages its objects. Blindly using `shared_ptr` can easily lead to circular references, i.e., memory leaks. Of course, you **could** write an answer, addressing all of the details. Comments will inevitably be simplifications, and debating which simplification is better is a waste of time.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh sure, but I was specifically commenting on what the equivalent in Java would be, and that would be an `std::shared_ptr`. I would definitely  not recommend using `std::shared_ptr` here (see one of my comments to Popescu Ion).

Comment: @AVH — no, `shared_ptr` would **not** be equivalent. Again: blindly using `shared_ptr` leads to circular references (i.e., memory leaks).

Comment: @PeteBecker Ah, right. Yeah, I guess there's not really an identical type of pointer in C++.